# Remove method in Python LinkedList using an index

Tags: python, python-2.7, linked-list

```
class Node(object):

   def __init__(self, data, next):
     self.data = data
     self.next = next


class LinkedList(object):

    head = None
    tail = None

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node: 
            print  node.data, 
            node = node.next 

    def add_front(self, data):
        node = Node(data, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node

    def remove(self, index):
        curr_node = self.head
        prev_node = None
        while curr_node and index>=0:
            if index == 0:

                if prev_node is not None:
                    prev_node.next = curr_node.next
                else:
                    self.head = curr_node.next

                index = index - 1   
            prev_node = curr_node
            curr_node = curr_node.next
```

So, I wanted to implement a remove method using index in python but it does not seem to be working. I think I'm messing something with replacing the nodes but can't figure out which one. So a little help needed here.

Comment: can you explain the 'not seem to be working' part? Any specific tets input that fails, or error?

Comment: whats the `index = index - 1` for, are you sure the indentation is correct for that line? are you trying to delete at index or all nodes upto and including index?